# Compile and run shuttle application

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors, dependencies

I"m want to learn and contribute to the shuttle application at git :

https://github.com/timusus/Shuttle

i"m experienced developer but i cant seem to compile this repository .

using :
Android Studio 3.0 beta 6

branch dev

1 . getting this error when i try to do gradle sync :

```
Warning:One of the plugins you are using supports Java 8 language features. To try the support built into the Android plugin, remove the following from your build.gradle:
    apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
To learn more, go to https://d.android.com/r/tools/java-8-support-message.html

Error:Failed to resolve: leakcanary-android

Error:Failed to resolve: recyclerview-fastscroll
```

2 .  the project using dependencies in a way i don't understand for example :

```
   compile libs.cardView
    compile libs.design
    compile libs.palette
    compile libs.prefCompat
    compile libs.prefCompatv14
    compile libs.recyclerView
    compile libs.supportv4
    compile libs.firebaseCore
```

I understand that the names here are constants but when to i see the value of that keys ?

Comment: 1) [Don't use beta 3](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/08/android-studio-30-beta-3-is-now.html). Upgrade as soon as possible. 2) You need Java 8 (meaning have it installed) 3) add retrolambda to your dependencies and see if that works

Comment: Thanks, i"m using beta6 i miss wrote . retrolambda is allready exist in some of the libraries . i think i support java 8

Answer (score 0):

By default, Android Studio 3.0 Betas offer you to use new alphas/betas of Android Gradle Plugin 3.0.0. These gradle plugins go with support of Java 8 features.
So if you want to use Retrolambda, then remove next block from [Shuttle/app/build.gradle](https://github.com/timusus/Shuttle/blob/dev/app/build.gradle):

```
// Used to enable Java8 features
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
```

Or remove

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

if you want to use Java 8 support from gradle plugin.

Declaration of ***leakcanary-android*** and ***recyclerview-fastscroll*** you can find in [dependencies.gradle](https://github.com/timusus/Shuttle/blob/dev/dependencies.gradle):

```
ext.versions = [
    ...
    leakCanary  : "1.5.1",
    ...
    fastScroll  : "1.0.15",
    ...
]
```

and

```
ext.libs = [
    ...
    fastScroll : "com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:$versions.fastScroll",
    ...
    leakCanaryDebug : "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:$versions.leakCanary",
    leakCanaryRel : "com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:$versions.leakCanary",
    ...
]
```